# Can't edit specific CSS file

Tags: css, wordpress

When I am in Wordpress I can only edit

```
http://.../wp-content/themes/enigma/style.css?ver=4.0.1
```

however I need to edit

```
http://.../wp-content/themes/enigma/css/enigma-theme.css?ver=4.0.1
```

How would I go about gaining access and edit this file?

Comment: Take a look at FileZilla.

Comment: one place you might look in case it will show up is in the Wordpress Dashboard - in Appearance/editor, towards the top right there will be a dropdown to select themes - make sure you have your main theme - then check in the bottom if you see the enigma-theme.css -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style.css` is for adding `css` to your site. I would add any `css` to this file as any edits to the `enigma-theme.css` may get overwritten if you update the theme.

You could:

- use a plugin like [simple custom css](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) to add any css to the site.
- download the `enigma-theme.css` file, edit and re-upload use [filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to download and upload the file.
- download the whole theme change the name [see here](http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2012/09/renaming-your-wordpress-theme/) this would prevent any overwrites if the theme updates as it will be your custome theme at that point

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I've used the first solution and overridden the code.
Cheers!